# AWS RDS metric for memory utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, monitoring, datadog

Does AWS RDS offer a metric for monitoring the memory utilization? I see one metric called `freeable_memory` which is how much available memory an instance has. I'd like to create an alert when the memory usage reaches a certain percetage of the total memory but can't seem to find a metric which supports that, similar to `cpuutilization`. I also found a metric called `acuutilization` in datadog but haven't been able to find what that metric tracks.

Comment: But you can define an alert based on freeable memory. You will just need to invert the percentage. E.g if you want to have an alert on 80% usage on total memory then you can have 20% available on freeable memory. If you need to know which thread, user is using how much memory, then enhanced monitoring mentioned in the answer is what you need.

Comment: Freeable memory is an absolute metric, not a percentage. How would I make it a percentage without the database reporting how much memory it has?

Comment: I think you won't get it in enhanced monitoring as well. You will probably need a third party solution. Zabbix is a free and can get you this.

Comment: You can also create a metric yourself. You can add math to your queries. For example, if you have 2 GB total ram, you can do this. https://ibb.co/JqyW2vL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [enhanced monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html). Enhanced Monitoring has a metric called *Active Memory*:

> The amount of assigned memory, in kilobytes.

Sounds to me like something that could be useful for you. But be aware that you also get additional costs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.overview.html#USER_Monitoring.OS.cost

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in Terraform to create an alarm based on percentage of utilization.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "rds_memory_utilization" {
  alarm_name          = format("RDS-MemoryUtilization-%s-%s", var.env, var.identifier)
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = var.memory_evaluation_periods
  threshold           = var.memory_threshold
  datapoints_to_alarm = var.memory_datapoints_to_alarm
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  alarm_description   = format("%s-%s %s%% memory utilization", var.env, var.identifier, var.memory_threshold)
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  alarm_actions       = [data.aws_sns_topic.ops_sns.arn]
  ok_actions          = [data.aws_sns_topic.ops_sns.arn]

  metric_query {
    id    = "percent_memory_utilization"
    label = "percent_memory_utilization"
    # need to convert rds_total_memory to bytes first, get the percentage of available memory and then subtract to calculate the memory utilization
    expression  = "100 - ((m1/(${var.rds_total_memory}*1048576))*100)"
    return_data = "true"
  }

  metric_query {
    id = "m1"

    metric {
      metric_name = "FreeableMemory"
      namespace   = "AWS/RDS"
      period      = var.memory_period
      stat        = "Maximum"
      dimensions = {
        DBInstanceIdentifier = var.identifier
      }
    }
  }

  provider = aws.env
}
```